# Retrieve list of Strings from Spray path

Tags: spray, spray-dsl

I have a base url of an API like this

```
http://host/api/categories
```

In my database categories are a tree based model.  I'd like to be able to have an api where I can hit urls like

```
http://host/api/categories/delivery

http://host/api/categories/delivery/food

http://host/api/categories/delivery/medicine
```

How can I pull everything after the word "categories" as a single string (and split it myself) or as a list of strings?  Essentially getting List("delivery","medicine") out of the third example would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Super easy answer just use

```
pathPrefix("listJobCategories" / Segments) { query =>
```

and query will be List[String]